# Monte Carlo simulation of a system of polymer chain

Tags: python-3.x, montecarlo

I want to perform Monte Carlo simulation to the particles which are interacting via Lennard-Jones potential + FENE potential. I'm getting negative values in the FENE potential which have the log value in it. The error is "RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in log return (-0.5 * K * R**2 * np.log(1-((np.sqrt(rij2) - r0) / R)**2))" The FENE potential is given by:[image]

```py
import numpy as np

def gen_chain(N, R0):
    x = np.linspace(1, (N-1)*0.8*R0, num=N)
    y = np.zeros(N)
    z = np.zeros(N)
    return np.column_stack((x, y, z))

def lj(rij2):
    sig_by_r6 = np.power(sigma/rij2, 3)
    sig_by_r12 = np.power(sig_by_r6, 2)
    lje = 4.0 * epsilon * (sig_by_r12 - sig_by_r6)
    return lje

def fene(rij2):
    return (-0.5 * K * R**2 * np.log(1-((np.sqrt(rij2) - r0) / R)**2))

def total_energy(coord):
    # Non-bonded
    e_nb = 0
    for i in range(N):
        for j in range(i-1):
            ri = coord[i]
            rj = coord[j]
            rij = ri - rj
            rij2 = np.dot(rij, rij)
            if (np.sqrt(rij2) < rcutoff):
                e_nb += lj(rij2)
    # Bonded
    e_bond = 0
    for i in range(1, N):
        ri = coord[i]
        rj = coord[i-1]
        rij = ri - rj
        rij2 = np.dot(rij, rij)
        e_bond += fene(rij2)
    return e_nb + e_bond

def move(coord):
    trial = np.ndarray.copy(coord)
    for i in range(N):
        delta = (2.0 * np.random.rand(3) - 1) * max_delta
        trial[i] += delta
    return trial

def accept(delta_e):
    beta = 1.0/T
    if delta_e <= 0.0:
        return True
    random_number = np.random.rand(1)
    p_acc = np.exp(-beta*delta_e)
    if random_number < p_acc:
        return True
    return False


if __name__ == "__main__":

    # FENE parameters
    K = 40
    R = 0.3
    r0 = 0.7

    # LJ parameters
    sigma = r0/0.33
    epsilon = 1.0

    # MC parameters
    N = 50 # number of particles
    rcutoff = 2.5*sigma
    max_delta = 0.01
    n_steps = 10000000
    T = 0.5

    coord = gen_chain(N, R)
    energy_current = total_energy(coord)

    traj = open('traj.xyz', 'w') 

    for step in range(n_steps):
        if step % 1000 == 0:
            traj.write(str(N) + '\n\n')
            for i in range(N):
                traj.write("C %10.5f %10.5f %10.5f\n" % (coord[i][0], coord[i][1], coord[i][2]))
            print(step, energy_current)
        coord_trial = move(coord)
        energy_trial = total_energy(coord_trial)
        delta_e =  energy_trial - energy_current
        if accept(delta_e):
            coord = coord_trial
            energy_current = energy_trial

    traj.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that calculating `rij2 = np.dot(rij, rij)` in `total energy` with the constant values you use is always a very small number. Looking at the expression inside the log used to calculate FENE, `np.log(1-((np.sqrt(rij2) - r0) / R)**2)`, I first noticed that you're taking the square root of `rij2` which is not consistent with the formula you provided.

Secondly, notice that `((rij2 - r0) / R)**2` is the same as `((r0 - rij2) / R)**2`, since the sign gets lost when squaring. Because `rij2` is very small (already in the first iteration -- I checked by printing the values), this will be more or less equal to `((r0 - 0.05)/R)**2` which will be a number bigger than 1. Once you subtract this value from 1 in the log expression, `1-((np.sqrt(rij2) - r0) / R)**2` will be equal to `np.nan` (standing for "Not A Number"). This will propagate through all the function calls (for example, calling `energy_trial = total_energy(coord_trial)` will effectively set `energy_trial` to np.nan), until an error will be raised by some function.

Maybe you could do something with `np.isnan()` call, documented [here](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.isnan.html). Moreover, you should check how you iterate through the `coord` (there's some inconsistencies throughout the code) -- I suggest you check the [code review community](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/) as well.

Comment: I took the square root to eliminate the square of the rij2 and make it rij which is mentioned in the formula. How you got the number 0.05 for the rij2? I'm trying make it a bigger number by changing the x values in gen_chain function. Can you please suggest something about this?

Comment: I see. I ran the code you provided and checked the values for rij2. I'm not familiar with the physics so it's hard for me to say what's wrong and right about the way you're computing things.